# Как отловить правило для свойства товара

Tags: php, битрикс, администрирование

Есть интернет-магазин, весь функционал работает, но на половину товаров накладывается определенный стикер (например, скидка при оплате).

вся проблема в том, что не получается отловить откуда система берет правило/условие, чтобы вывести данный стикер.
в 1с у таких настроек нет, т.е. сторону 1с я исключил, вручную также никто не проставляет (там тысячи товаров).

практические все возможные скидки и правила для корзины я отключены/удалены, но  все система откуда-то берет и накладывает.

прошу рекомендации как убрать данное правило/условие, а точнее где оно возможно может быть прописано.

ps: гуглил/искал/ суппорт битрикса сказали это не их тема, они занимаются стандартным функционалом.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего прописано правило в шаблонах каталога которое реагирует к примеру на цену товара. Посмотрите следующие шаблоны:

```
site.ru/bitrix/templates/Ваш_шаблон/components/bitrix/catalog/ms_catalog/bitrix/catalog.section/Шаблон/template.php
```

По аналогии посмотрите вместо папки "catalog.section" в "catalog.section.list" и "catalog.element". Зависит от того где выводится "стикер" в карточке товара или в разделах.

Еще вариант могли прописать в файлах которые находятся тут site.ru/bitrix/templates/Ваш_шаблон/components/bitrix/catalog/ms_catalog/ в файлах element.php, section.php, sections.php

Так не правильно но иногда прописывают.

Comment: К сожалению, даже нет каталога ms_catalog, в остальных каталогах ничего похожего нет.